# Spring boot actuator in console application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

I have a console application using Spring. My application is connecting on a database and a JMS server.
I would like to know at the start up of my application, if it is well connected to the databse and the JMS.
I know that spring-boot-actuator do that efficiently and esealy, but it expose rest endpoints. I would like to know if it's possible to get Spring actuator's beans to get status informations, database and JMS status.

Is it possible ?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you wanting to communicate with it if not via HTTP? I believe there is also some JMX support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your second question: Yes, springs actuators provide autoconfigured health indicators when they are found on classpath, see [this list](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_auto_configured_healthindicators) for more details (datasource and JMS is provided).

But you can also easily implement your own status informations by just implementing `HealthIndicator` and adding it as a `@Component`, more details can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators).

You can expose them either with REST or with JMX, the exposure can be configured via `application.properties`, details can be found in [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints).

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints), endpoints can be exposed through HTTP or JMX. By default, Spring will expose actuator endpoints over JMX unless you configure it not to do so.

There is [a table showing which endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints) are enabled in JMX and HTTP by default. If you want to enable them on HTTP, there are several security settings you should be aware of before exposing them (see docs link above).

In order to expose actuator endpoints over HTTP, you'll need to include the `spring-starter-web` start in your build.

Gradle:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Again, check the security settings before doing this. Newer versions of boot should give you a good safe set of defaults.